# Make a horizontal scroll bar sticky/fixed at the bottom on vertical scroll?

Tags: html, jquery, css, scrollbar, sticky-footer

I have a table that has a set height & am trying to get the horizontal scroll bar to remain sticky (fixed) to the bottom of the page when scrolling vertically - is there anyway I can achieve this? Either pure CSS or involving JS

Comment: can you provide your code or a small codepen example

Answer (score 0):

Try this css

```
.scrolling {
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: -30px;
}
```